# Get index from value in 2D grid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D array of type `Cell` that creates a grid of cells in Unity.

```
private Cell[,] cells;

private void Start()
{
    cells = new Cell[mapSize.x, mapSize.y];
}
```

Currently I can access all the cells from `Map` by passing in the matching x and y value. Example:

```
private Cell GetCell(int x, int y)
{
    return cells[x, y];
}
```

Now I want to get the matching x and y value by passing in a cell object.

My solution would be creating the `Cell` component like this

```
public class Cell : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void InitCell(int indexX, int indexY) // This gets called when intantiating the Cell
    {
        x = indexX;
        y = indexY;
    }
}
```

but do I really have to store these information at the cell component too?

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Do you want to search the cells to get the x value and what matches that value in y ? Or do you want to just find x and y values ?

Comment: I want to get x and y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use of a simple function like this:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> CoordinatesOf(Cell[,] cells, Cell value)
{
    int w = cells.GetLength(0); // width
    int h = cells.GetLength(1); // height

    for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < h; ++j)
        {
            if (cells[i, j] == value)
                 return Tuple.Create(i, j);
        }
    }

     return Tuple.Create(-1, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont **have** to.
You could also just do something like

```
foreach(var cell in cells)
{
     if(cell == cellToFind)
     {
          //Gotcha
     }
}
```

But storing the x,y inside your cells would be faster